# App cannot open in Android 4.4.4. - only release version, not on debug, not on emulator

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm developing an app which doesn't run in `Android 4.4.4`.

**Detail:**
Only release version, cause when in debug time, usb plugged, runs smoothly. Created an emulator with 4.4.4 image and, same way, runs fine. The app simply refuses to open ("The application needs to be closed").

**Do not know how to track the problem:**
No logcat, no special message, not a clue, I'm unable to debug it.

**Mean time:**
Tested in many emulators sdk versions and always runs fine. My matter is with `a physical device running 4.4.4`.

**My ambient:**

```
Android Studio 2.1.2
JRE 1.7.0_79-b15 amd64
Gradle 2.1.2
Compiler sdk api 23
Build tools 23.0.3
Min. sdk 13
Target sdk 18
Minify enabled (release version)
```

**Dependencies:**

```
com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+
com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0
com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try change Target sdk 18 to 19?. Because [Android 4.4 is API Level 19](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html)

Don't forget to disable proguard first to make sure that wasn't because of proguard.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. This didn't solve the problems.